# How to verify an Integer? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How do verify a value entered in an input box is an integer? If it's not I want the input box to show up again no harm done. Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim int As Integer
If Integer.TryParse("12345", int) Then
  'use int variable it holds the converted value
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

as @OneFineDay said you have to use `Integer.TryParse`, now to repeat the question untill it is an integer you can do this:

```
dim ans = As String
dim int As Integer
dim isInteger As Boolean = False

do While Not isInteger
    ans = InputBox("Give me an Integer")
    isInteger = Integer.TryParse(ans, int)
End do

''Here int holds an integer
```

Comment: What does "12345" represent in the parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be an input validation question without a Regex answer, so if you want to make it more complicated than it needs to be then you can use something like

```
Dim expression As New Regex("^-?\d+$")
If Not expression.IsMatch(textBox1.Text) Then
    textBox1.Text = String.Empty
End If
```

The Regex pattern will look at all entered text, and match iff there is zero or one minus signs followed by at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

12345 represents text that you can either enter manually in quotes or can grab from an input box like this:

`Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Enter integer here"),myInt)` ,such that the input from the inputbox is the one that will be converted into the integer variable,this saves you memory no need to declare another variable.

The loop in @bto.rdz 's answer is quite handy though,especially if you want the user to enter an integer no matter what